# Encrypted password replacement

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have encrypted passwords specific to each environment. It has some special characters. Below is one sample from development environment (which has forward slash)

```
    $$Param_INFA_USER=USR_DF
    $$Param_INFA_PASS=1OFR6pSbNq/yvLtpxHbC9E9KvloTj5tRGpzr9dCMD7E=
v_prst_pwd=`grep -i "\\$\\$Param_INFA_PASS" param_file.parm` | tr -d ' '
v_lbl_pwd=`grep -i "\\$\\$Param_INFA_PASS" param_file.parm | cut -d '=' -f1`
sed -i 's/'$v_prst_pwd'/'$v_lbl_pwd'='$envspfc_pwd'/g' param_file.parm
sed -i s/$$Param_INFA_PASS=**1OFR6pSbNq/yvLtpxHbC9E9KvloTj5tRGpzr9dCMD7E=**/$$Param_INFA_PASS=ABC/g param_file.parm
```

I am trying to replace passwords and got below issue.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 74: unknown option to `s'
```

How to escape special characters when replacing a string which is a  variable (not aware of position of special characters).

Comment: What shell is that? I can hardly tell what this code is about.

Comment: Does this code actually run? What does `$$Param_INFA_USER=USR_DF` do?

Comment: I have copy pasted file data which has user name and password.

Comment: I have spaces before username & password variables.

Comment: This is not a shell script, at least not for a shell that I have ever heard of. `$$Param_INFA_PASS`, really with double dollar signs?

Comment: Those are Informatica specfic variables in a file

Comment: I have to replace user names & passwords as per environment. I am facing issue when replacing password as it has special characters in it

Comment: Your password looks like a shell script, at least you say it is a password.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `Param_INFA_PASS` is evidently [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). It can contain letters, digits and the characters `+`, `/` and `=`.

For plain grep, none of these characters are special. Beware that for egrep or `grep -E`, the character `+` is special and would need to be escaped. Don't use `grep -i`: Base64 is case-sensitive.

For sed, none of these characters are special if you do it right. In the `s` command, you can use any character¹ instead of `/`. So pick one that isn't used in Base64, for example

```
sed -e "s~^PASSWORD=$old_password\$~$new_password~g"
```

¹  <sub>Except newline and backslash.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

sed **does not** use `/` as its separator.

Because of the examples, we think that sed uses `/` as a separator. However it can use any character.

e.g. `sed 's/abc/def/'` can be written as `sed 's^abc^def^`. What ever follows the `s` is the separator.

If there is a character that is not used in the input text then you can use this to your advantage (Maybe choose a non-printing character).